# Android Memory Usage and Objects in Memory not being released in 1.6 and 2.1

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm checking my app for Memory Leaks/Usage and came across something weird that I've only seen so far in Android 1.6 and 2.1.  After clicking around in the app a bit and I run "adb shell dumpsys meminfo" for my application, I see the following:

```
DUMP OF SERVICE meminfo:
Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 34639912 Realtime: 153524709

** MEMINFO in pid 5778 [com.app.myapp] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:    14336     4679      N/A    19015
       allocated:    13971     4139      N/A    18110
            free:      280      540      N/A      820
           (Pss):     2986     4181    13491    20658
  (shared dirty):      972     3948      620     5540
    (priv dirty):     2876     3224    10976    17076

 Objects
           Views:      545        ViewRoots:        4
     AppContexts:       32       Activities:       31
          Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
   Local Binders:       43    Proxy Binders:       79
Death Recipients:        2
 OpenSSL Sockets:        1

 SQL
            heap:       91          dbFiles:        0
       numPagers:        4   inactivePageKB:        0
    activePageKB:        0

 Asset Allocations
    zip:/data/app/com.app.myapp.apk:/resources.arsc: 119K
```

As you can see, nothing is getting deallocated/GC'd, the Activities are piling up, the AppContexts, etc. until the app just crashes with an OutOfMemoryError.  This doesn't happen on 2.2+.

Can anybody give me some insight into why this is happening?  I have a feeling it's either something simple, or it's just something weird with my app, but I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

FYI, I've reproduced this in a 1.6 and 2.1 emulator, as well as my G1 running 1.6.  A recent crash report from a user also shows this, which they were running 2.1 on a Droid Eris.  Let me know if any more details/code is needed to help with this.

**##UPDATE##**

Thanks to the info from momo, I was able to track down some memory leak issues, which drastically cut down on the amount of Activities/AppContexts that would show in the Objects list of meminfo.

The number is now down to around the number of actual activities that are in my application, so it seems that on older versions of Android, it will show the total amount of objects your app is consuming.  On newer versions it won't, though that could just be only the case on my test devices.

Comment: Is this still the same app (My Fishing companion)? If so what are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: It is.  Basically just click around going from activity to activity and you'll start seeing the objects pile up.  Only seems to happen in 1.6 and 2.1 as far as I can tell though.

Comment: Per comment in the answer below you tried MAT. Have you tried these steps: 1. Look at # of instances for Activity that get stuck. 2. Look at the root path to GC? That's what I usually do if the # of activities are piling up, especially if the root path to GC is not ViewRoot. If it is not the ViewRoot then something else is holding up that you would need to cut the reference of. If you still need to debug, I could put a detailed answer illustrating the process. I can't specifically run MAT on your app since it's coming from the Market

Comment: Thanks momo. Ill take a look, but I may not know exactly what to look for. Some pointers would be great

Comment: I've detailed the steps that I normally take for the kind of bugs that you are facing. I hope it is helpful for you. Debugging OOM is an art + educated guess + a bit of luck + perseverance, I wish you good luck and let me know if I can be of further help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a clear picture on why Activities are held up, I normally use MAT and then look at Path to GC root from the Activity that get stuck.

I've a created a simple project which load simple TestActivity in order to illustrate the process. Below is the code for it:

```
package com.so;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Here are the steps:

- Dump the hprof on the running process via DDMS "Dump HPROF File" function
- Assuming you have MAT installed, this should bring up the MAT screen
- Now filter based on your activity package, for the sample above, it is com.so. Screenshot for this process is below:

[image: MAT Histogram Screen]

- Now you want to see if this has a clear path to GC. You do that by right clicking the Activity and show all references as shown below:

[image: Show all references]

You should see that your Activity is held by com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView and no one else. If this is the a case, you are ok and this Activity will be eventually reclaimed by GC.

Now I will do change my class to include a static variable that will hold its own instance:

```
package com.so;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    static ArrayList memoryLeakList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create a deliberate static list to cause the leak
        TestActivity.memoryLeakList = new ArrayList();
        TestActivity.memoryLeakList.add(this);
    }
}
```

And if I run the code hprof with the same steps, I now get the reference of the Activity is held by the ArrayList and not the com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView signifying that there is possibility of a leak if I don't clean up the array

[image: Memory Leak caused by ArrayList]

Now, you don't have to do that for every Activity, what I would do just briefly run the app and then dump the HPROF. You would then again filter by package to get the snapshot of your application. In the initial Histogram, you should be suspicious for any Activity that has number of instances more than one after hitting GC button in DDMS and start investigating from there.

One more note, on my 2.1 phones, I couldn't get the HPROF via DDMS, so I did it through the emulator following these steps:

- Go to ./adb shell

  - Type ps to get the pid of your app process
  - Type kill -10 , you should see in your logcat that it is dumping the memory to /data/misc
  - If you get permission denied, make sure you read/write on that folder by doing chmod 777 data/misc
- Pull the hprof generated by either using DDMS File Explorer in Eclipse or pull command
- Since the hprof is dalvik based, in order to use it with memory profiling tools you need to convert it first via [hprof-conv](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hprof-conv.html) available in the tools directory of your Android SDK installation

  ```
  Run ./hprof-conv [source dump] [target dump]
  ```

Comment: Thanks momo!  I'll take a look at this as soon as I get back to my system.

Comment: I took a look at a heap dump and for one of my activities it showed the path as: Activity > mContext(com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorWindow) > mView(android.view.ViewRoot) > this$0(android.view.ViewRoot$1 Native Stack.  Is this a potential leak and where would I go from this point?

Comment: @hooked82 This doesn't seem like one. If you go to other Activity, hit gc button in DDMS and take another hprof, does the Activity disappear? We should focus on Activities where the number of instance keep going up and then pick one of those and run the same process

Comment: Ok, I've found a few Activities that were being leaked and I've been able to fix the ones I've come across so far.  It seems that the amount of Activities shown when I run dumpsys meminfo isn't as many as before, but still a good amount.  Is this just a case when you run meminfo in 2.2+ it doesn't show the amount of Objects where as 1.6-2.1 do show the actual amounts of Objects?  If this is the case then I think I just need to fix the memory leaks and I'll be set.

Comment: The number of Activities in dumpsys is not implemented in all phones. I've seen some phones (even 2.2) show the number and some don't. Since that number is not shown in every phone, I always rely more on the number of instances through MAT. The amount of time to GC the activity is not instantaneous as well (seems slower in older phone, but that could be just my perception), what I would do after cleaning up the code is to go back to MAT, go to one Activity that you suspect that you've fixed and move to other. Take a snapshot in MAT after you hit GC and see the previous Activity is gone.

Comment: Another thing in case you haven't done it, double check if you are using ApplicationContext as described in [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) when passing Context around unless you specifically need the activity. It has tripped me in the past and caused memory leak.

Comment: Thanks momo!  I've update my original question with some info.  Basically I'm down to only one instance of every Activity except for one which is cause by a leak in LocationManager (That will be a whole new question).  This is the best answer, which got me to where I needed to be to find the leaks in my application, which was causing very high amounts of Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use Memory Analyzer (MAT) to view your process Heap.
http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: I've gone that route, it gets me nowhere.